# Correct Flag (if any) for this Question

Tags: discussion

I stumbled across [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/53869/remove-rows-from-dataset-from-a-column-with-more-than-5-missing-columns) and I'm unsure of how to handle this.

This question was answered in the comments, so if this was the only "issue" - I would normally just comment to the users involved to post an answer/accept the answer.

However, this question seems to be something that StackOverflow can answer. There are multiple questions that answer this. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128856/python-drop-row-if-two-columns-are-nan) for example.

I want to be a contributing member of this Site. So what would be the correct action (if any action at all) to take on this question?

Comment: Vote to close as off topic...  Also without some code, that would also be off topic at Stack Overflow.

Comment: @StephenRauch, thank you for the reply and also taking action.